# Why does Poe Dameron leave Jakku without BB-8?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, when Finn and Poe Dameron escape the Star Destroyer *Finalizer*, Poe flies back to Jakku over Finn's protests, insisting he has to pick up BB-8 — and what BB-8's carrying — as per his mission.

But when they crash land and Finn goes to look for him, Poe is already gone. Later, we learn he returned to the Resistance base without BB-8, as BB-8 was with Finn and Rey.

Why did he make the gamble to return to Jakku only to leave after he crashed? For all he knows, BB-8 was still somewhere on Jakku.

Comment: In Star Wars, why does- The Force! Next question!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

He left because he had no way to reconnect with BB-8 and knew the droid could take care of itself for a while till he got help. From Alan Dean Foster's novelization:

> He was alive on the surface of Jakku. Alive and alone. There was no way of telling if Finn had been as fortunate. More important, where was BB-8?
>   **The droid could take care of himself, he felt. Poe knew if he could just get offworld and reconnect with the Resistance, a way could be found to recover the droid**. All he needed was a ship. He’d already stolen one. Could he steal another?

He had no idea what happened to BB-8 till he saw the droid with Finn later:

> “I wasn’t dead, just momentarily out of it,” the pilot explained. “Came around long enough to see that you had got out. Pulled out of the dive just long enough to set down—hard. Impact threw me clear. Woke up at night; no you, no ship, no nothing. Went looking—in the wrong direction. Got picked up by some itinerant trader.” He grinned. “Tell you all about it sometime.” A plaintive beep caused him to turn and look down. “Beebee-Ate says that you saved him.”
>   Finn eyed the droid. “It wasn’t just me.” A slow smile spread across his face and his eyes twinkled. “Tell you all about it sometime.”
>   “**Either way, you completed my mission.” Poe gestured at their surroundings. “Beebee-Ate is here, where he was supposed to come all along**. And you saved my jacket.”

Comment: Damn, he actually writes out "beebee-ate" when characters say the name? That is worse than all the "artoo" nonsense.

Comment: @JasonK - that's a very very standard notation in both Disney canon books (including novelizations) and Legends books

Comment: Maybe, but it looks ridiculous. Artoo isn't much longer than "R2" and C3PO is usually cut to "threepio". Maybe it is just the "ate" instead of "eight" that is bothering me. I can see doing it once or twice just to establish how the acronyms are pronounced or if it is necessary to elongate the word ("Artoooooo, where are you?"), but it seems silly to use it in normal conversation when the acronym is used other context.

Comment: @JasonK - I think it's meant to be stylistically showing that this is a person anthropomorphising the droid. Or something.

Comment: +1  "Woke up at night..." this was also stated in the movie as well.

Comment: So he just basically left when BB-8 didn't come to him? Since this is supported by the novelization, it's the canonical answer, but Poe's reasoning here seems kind of weak. The scenario posed by Royal Canadian Bandit seems much more plausible... 

The whole reason he attempted to return to Jakku instead of heading toward the Resistance in the first place was to find BB-8 (not that they would have gotten very far, as I assume TIE Fighters still don't have hyperdrives).

Comment: @user339676 - that's not quite how I interpret it. He didn't have any good way of getting BB-8 himself, so he went back to the Resistance to get help. Remember, when he wanted to go "back", he had Finn AND a working Tie/SF - and ENTIRELY different situation.

Comment: @JasonK - OK, I admit, the -"ate" bothered me visually while reading at first too, so I can't argue too much :)

Comment: @user339676 - of course voting is 100% personal and you have a right to vote any which way you like, but I would like to point out that the purpose of this site is to mostly provide answers accurate **in-universe**.

Comment: @user339676 - Imagine reading 2 answers on StackOverflow, one says "this pretty piece of code does X" (which you really like and it's elegant) and the second answer has a boring, inelegant piece of code. Except the code in answer #1 doesn't compile and if it did, doesn't work correctly. Would you prefer the elegant but wrong code in #1 or boring working #2 answer? And if you vote for #1, consider that **the votes help mislead future site visitors, who will (if enough people who think the same way as you, and upvote elegant answer) be convinced that the wrong code is the one they should use

Comment: @user339676 - sorry if the example doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DVK - If I'm not mistaken, I did mark your answer as the accepted one, which seems to be the one you're referring to #2 in your comment I believe. Because it is the in-universe official canon, I assumed that is what users on this question board would consider the acceptable one, though I disagree with the narrative since the fact #1 makes much more sense. Or do you mean your response is more analogous to #1?

Comment: I guess I'm somewhat uncertain by what you mean by **in-universe**. I can still change the accepted answer if the other one seems to better fit the maxims of this question board, being that it feels more in line with the character behavior we see in the other films (another **in-universe** appropriation).

Comment: @user339676 - basically, what I'm trying to say is, if the canon material says "Sky is green" in some movie; and you go like "No, that doesn't make sense, the sky is blue" - then you are wrong, even if what you say makes more sense in "real world" outside the film you're discussing. Yes, my answer is the accepted one, I was merely responding to your comment about "poe's reasoning is weak so I like the other answer better". We (as people discussing the film) **are not given a choice** between the two equally valid reasonings for Poe to choose from - the film creators chose one for us.

Comment: I see and completely understand. I suppose that particular comment was implying a greater discussion of the source material rather than the answer itself. There is an inherent dissatisfaction with having to reach for outside materials to explain fundamental plot details in a narrative. I suppose I was really searching for a sensible answer in the *story we see* rather than *the story we research*. Furthermore, the novelizations do sometimes contradict the films and should be taken with a grain of salt. (Luke having the call sign "Blue 5" instead of "Red 5" for *A New Hope*, for example.)

Comment: @user339676 - that is most certainly true. TFA novelization does have contradictions with the film as well :(. However, this one happened NOT to be one :)

Comment: While this may be technically correct, it just seems like bad writing to me.

Comment: @xdhmoore - wait... you mean... as opposed to all the OTHER bad writing in Star Wars? :)

Comment: Lol, I guess I just wanted to complain

Comment: @xdhmoore - well, you're in the right place. I am certain there's oodles of people here (**myself included**) who totally agree with you in that complaint!

Comment: "He was alive on the surface of Jakku. Alive and alone. There was no way of telling if Finn had been as fortunate. More important, where was BB-8? The droid could take care of himself, he felt. Poe knew if he could just get offworld and reconnect with the Resistance, a way could be found to recover the droid. All he needed was a ship. He’d already stolen one. Could he steal another?" This strikes me as lazy and shallow way of explaining why Poe didn't make much effort to search for BB8.

Answer (score 32):

## NOTE: This answer is contradicted by the novelization. See DVK's answer for details.

BB-8 left Jakku in a *very* public fashion, as

> Rey, Finn, and BB-8 ran from the attacking First Order, <s>stole</s> liberated the *Millennium Falcon* and flew away.

If Poe was trying to track down BB-8, it's plausible that he

> got as far as what was left of the scavenger settlement

and learned from witnesses that BB-8 had left the planet. In particular,

> Unkar Plutt, the junkyard owner who had previously held the *Millennium Falcon*

might have been eager to tell everyone how he had been robbed, because he was angry and hoping to get "his" property back.

In addition, BB-8

> made a strong impression in the scavenger settlement, with Unkar Plutt offering a high price to buy him, and others trying to steal him

so many would have noticed and remembered him.

Comment: Thumbs up for the <cross>stole</cross> liberated :D

Comment: Primarily opinion based, but quite logical following movie information.

Comment: This answer assumes that Poe got to settlement after Finn has already left the planet. For all we know, Poe left crash site before Finn. Unless he got lost on the way, he should have reached scavenger village before Finn.

Comment: IIRC, Poe tells Finn that he was knocked unconscious in the crash and woke up that night, after Finn and the others had left.

Comment: Didn't Poe say when he woke up, Finn was already gone?  If that's the case Finn would have been there first.  What I want to know is how much of that outpost survived if the First Order were carpet bombing the place.  Then who would still be around to explain to Poe where BB-8 was?

Comment: I recalled a quick shot of a pedestrian as the MF enters/exits a derelict star destroyer and thought that was probably Poe. Where to go from there, though...

Comment: I like this answer better, since it seems more plausible, but @DVK's answer is technically correct, since it's supported by the novelization. Still wish they had explored this more, though. The canonical version nullifies the whole reason they went back to Jakku in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely an out-of-universe answer, but in an interview with Oscar Isaac (who plays Poe Dameron) in *GQ* magazine titled, [“*Star Wars* Actor Reveals Which Character Was Supposed to Die in *The Force Awakens*”](http://www.gq.com/story/star-wars-the-force-awakens-character-death) the actor sheds some light on some of the awkwardness of this moment—and it’s “magical” resolution—in the final film; bold emphasis is mine:

> …Abrams had pitched him the character of Poe Dameron, a badass fighter
>   pilot battling against the remnants of the Empire.
>
> “He’s amazing!” said Abrams.
>
> “Sounds good!” thought Isaac, whose first experience in a movie
>   theater had been seeing The Empire Strikes Back.
>
> **“He opens the whole movie!” said Abrams.**
>
> “Sounds great!” thought Isaac.
>
> **“And then,” Abrams went on. “He dies.”**
>
> “Oh,” thought Isaac.
>
> “I’d done that before,” he told me later. “Set up the plot for the
>   main guy and then die spectacularly.” (He had played just such a role
>   in *The Bourne Legacy*.)

Then he goes on; again bold emphasis is mine:

> “I went back home [to New York], and I thought about it,” he says.
>   “Then I wrote him and said, ‘Okay. I’ll do it!’ I figured it would be
>   a cameo: I’ll come in, do my thing, and maybe it’s actually better not
>   to have to sign myself up for three movies.” By that time, though,
>   things had changed and Abrams soon wrote back: **“Never mind. I’ve
>   figured it out. You’re in the whole movie now.”**

So at the end of the day, it seems that Finn would have helped Poe escape, Poe would then pilot the TIE fighter with him and Finn to Jakku, and then the whole question of “What happened to Poe?” would simply be… He died and Finn is the one whose story goes on.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't seem unreasonable to infer he found out two humans had left Jakku in a stolen ship with a one of a kind droid in tow.