# Is Poe Dameron Force-Sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, poe-dameron

We know from *The Force Awakens* that Rey is Force-Sensitive, with speculation about what this could mean for her parentage being rife. Some people have also found some evidence which [may indicate that Finn is Force-Sensitive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111797/is-finn-force-sensitive).

On the other hand, what about Poe Dameron? Poe is an excellent pilot with a droid companion. [This](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) certainly *sounds* [familiar.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker) Being a great pilot has often been a [sign of Force sensitivity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/127315/3804) in the *Star Wars* universe.

**Is there any canon evidence in the *The Force Awakens* that Poe Dameron is Force-Sensitive?**

Comment: The problem with the question as it stands is that in about 8 months there will be new canon (in the form of Rogue One) that might  invalidate the answers below. And even more canon (in the form of Star Wars 8) that might invalidate those answers. The point of the "future works policy" is that it obviates the need to continually back-check questions where the answer has almost certainly been left unanswered by the writers...with the intention of revealing the answer in a future episode.

Comment: an absence of evidence is a form of evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I daresay at this point in time, we can only quote *Supreme Leader Snoke*:

> We shall see. We shall see!

More seriously, we do see feats of his (Poe, not Snoke) that are astonishing. His flying and shooting over Maz Kanata's castle would possibly make Anakin just throw up his hands and take up fishing:

- We see him shooting down a sequence of TIEs while doing a loop
- We see him selectively take out the troopers guarding Finn, Han and
  Chewie, leaving them without a scratch and standing around somewhat
  bemused

Then, over Starkiller Base, his flight with folded wings to blow up the wossname (my cat won't let me check the movie). This with almost zero visibility of the target. I admit I hadn't even known X-Wings can fire with the wings in neutral position (*Edit: and they can't and he didn't*). In ANH they specifically say "Wings into attack position", IIRC.

So, if you'd ask him, would he say "it just felt like the thing to do"?

Funnily enough, according to the *Secrets of The Force Awakens* on the DVD/Blueray release, Oscar Isaac says Poe was supposed to die. When he complained that this happened to him in too many movies, Abrams changed the script.

Edit: [Helpful link to fellow SEer on just that topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111994/64489)

Another Edit: Watching the scene again a few time, Poe **does** open the wings again after flying through that flaming gap. He does seem to use torpedoes and possibly his turbos both. It's a bit confusing: just what **is** the firing rate of proton torpedoes and how many do they have "loaded" (IIRC, proton torpedoes aren't physical missiles/torpedoes in our sense, but rather "packets of bundled protons, right?)

Comment: Marakai for firing in neutral position:  they can't from how I saw it he fired torpedoes and not his lasers, thus firing the torps IS possible, but firing the lasers very probably not. And for him not dying could that be why then the OTHER char died because someone had to?^^

Comment: To put into perspective. It is generally regarded that a pilot with over 5 confirmed kills to his name is given the title "ace". A particularly amazing feat is for a pilot to down over 5 pilots in a day...Poe does it in less than a minute.

Answer (score -1):

In *The Last Jedi*, the screen shows us as Finn and Rose get caught and are being forced to kneel in front of General Hux. In the next shot, it shows Poe holding up a gun to someone, but slowly taking it down, saying "They didn't make it." How else would he know they didn't make it without being Force sensitive?

Also, after he wakes up from being shot by an angry Princess Leia, he starts saying "No, no!!" and runs to the window and presses his hand against it. Through the window, you can see the ship that Rey is on (during the scene where Kylo brings her to Snoke). Here, Poe thinks Rey is in trouble. But how did he know she was on that exact ship? Simple answer. Poe is Force sensitive.

Though it hasn't been confirmed by Lucasfilm or by Rian Johnson, there are many pieces of evidence in the movies themselves.

Comment: A few of these seem like quite the stretch to be honest.