# What percentage of skilled pilots have been Force Sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

The Force can give one a significant advantage in all sorts of activities, from targeting to flying. Indeed, the relationship between Force skills and flying skills has (in the movies) proved sufficiently strong that Anakin, Luke, and Rey have all demonstrated impressive flying abilities, often without have flown something at all similar. It seems likely that most Force users are very good pilots.

But what percentage of very good pilots *in the movies, books, or comics* have been Force users?

This isn't asking whether most good pilots are Force sensitive; with the number of Force sensitives in the galaxy, that seems very unlikely.

**What percentage of excellent pilots shown *onscreen or on-page* in canon have been Force users?**

<sub>An "excellent" pilot must have been noted as such by others.</sub>

Comment: I think the definition of an [ace pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_ace) might work as a criterion.

Comment: How has @WadChaber not said 'Seven' on this yet?!

Comment: Anakin, Luke, Rey, Obi-Wan and Rey are the only people seen in the Star Wars *films* to pilot a ship and have force powers. But when you take into account the books and comics (let alone the TV shows) then we're into the dozens, maybe hundreds.

Comment: @Valorum - For someone of your talents and knowledge, dozens should be quite manageable. Obviously, I was only talking about canon.

Comment: @Adamant - The canon you're describing encompasses 13 feature films, half a dozen other films, more than a hundred episodes of the TV shows and nearly a hundred comic serials, not to mention more than a hundred books. It's pretty broad. Suffice to say 'every pilot who's a Jedi and pretty much no-one else'

Comment: It was a lot smaller back when I asked the question, you know.